# Symfony 1.4: if datatype is timestamp where is the "seconds" component?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I have a database column in `schema.yml`, its "`timestamp`"-ed. I generate a form based on model: `echo $form['deadline']->renderRow();`

But it only renders: **month/day/year hour/minute** - where is the "seconds" time component??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sfWidgetFormTime` has an option `with_seconds`, it defaults to false so you have to set it to true. You can do it in the form class' configure method like this:

```
$this->getWidget('deadline')->setOption('time', array('with_seconds' => true));
```